# SwiftUI List based on @FetchedRequest and filtering computed properties crashes

Tags: list, swiftui, fetchrequest

I have such code that has @FetchRequest loading Contacts then I have computed properties doing filter based on @State variable

```
 @FetchRequest var fetchRequest: FetchedResults<Contact>

    private var contacts : Array<Contact> {

        Array(fetchRequest).filter { contact in
            if self.sectionSelection == 1 {
                return contact.type == "person"
            } else if self.sectionSelection == 2 {
                return contact.type == "company"
            } else {
                 return true
            }
        }
    }

@State private var sectionSelection : Int = 0
```

But the List crashes with index out of range error!

```
 List {

            ForEach(0..<contacts.count) { i in

                ZStack {

                    NavigationLink(destination: ContactDetails(contact: contacts[i])) {
```

Comment: The problem might be about when 0..<contacts.count is being recomputed. Is it ever? It is not dependent on an observable which changes.

Comment: if i set breakpoint it seems to be recomputed. But I admit this solution isn't great maybe better will be to use something like indices, or enumerated() somehow?

Comment: You probably have to pipe the result through an ObservableObject which gets the updated list by being set by view taking the `fetchRequest` and the observable in and setting the fetchRequest on the observable inside. This way observable always gets updated when the `fetchRequest` updates. Then you update the @Published variable on the observer/the filter. I'm not sure it works though.

Comment: I have done this with Filtered sublist, i also just passing ids not managed object to another view i. Navigation destination. I think I also have changed something around ForEach/Identifiebla that makes this list filtering work

Comment: Can you share the solution please? I try to avoid `@FetchRequest` since I don't understand how to use it correctly. Would be awesome :)